# Windows 8.1 key

Tags: windows-8.1, installation

I want to know that when I was installing Windows 8.1, I was required to enter a product key which I already have. When I entered the key the setup checked the key and said that the key works. How the setup know either the key works or not without going online? Please help me.

Comment: installing or RE-installing? if the latter then you shouldn't even need a key

Answer (score 2):

Windows calls some functions form the pidgenx.dll:

```
[DllImport("pidgenx.dll", EntryPoint = "PidGenX", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        static extern int PidGenX(string productKey, string pkeyPath, string mspid, int unknownUsage, IntPtr productID, IntPtr digitalProductID, IntPtr digitalProductID4);
```

For pkeyPath Windows setup passes a path to [pkeyconfig.xrm-ms. In this file, the product key are defined and in the digitalProductID4 (last parameter), the Edition and Product key type (MSDN, Retail, Trial) is encoded](https://github.com/chughes-3/UpdateProductKey/blob/master/UpdateProductKeys/PidChecker.cs).

If Setup detects which Edition the key belongs to, it checks the Windows you try to install and if the Editions don't match you get an error.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](http://www.licenturion.com/xp/fully-licensed-wpa.txt) published article :

When you activate your copy of Windows, you are transmitting an Installation ID code to Microsoft either by phone or Internet depending on the method you choose to activate. Based on this, the Microsoft’s licensing system can determine whether or not the installed OS is genuine. If it is said to be genuine, then the system will receive the Activation ID which completes the activation process. If the activation is done through a telephone, the Activation ID needs to be entered manually to complete the activation process.

**What information does the Installation ID contain?**

This Installation ID is a 50-digit number which is derived from the following two data.

1. Product ID – It is actually derived from the 25-digit product key (the alphanumeric value that is printed on the sticker over the Windows CD/DVD case) that is entered during the installation of the operating system. The Product ID is used to uniquely identify your copy of Windows.
2. Hardware ID – This value is derived based on the hardware configuration of your computer.

The WPA system checks the following 10 categories of the computer hardware to derive the Hardware ID:

> Display Adapter
>
> SCSI Adapter
>
> IDE Adapter (effectively the motherboard)
>
> Network Adapter (NIC) and its MAC Address
>
> RAM Amount Range (i.e., 0-64mb, 64-128mb, etc.)
>
> Processor Type
>
> Processor Serial Number
>
> Hard Drive Device
>
> Hard Drive Volume Serial Number (VSN)
>
> CD-ROM / CD-RW / DVD-ROM

Thus, the Installation ID which is a combination of Product ID and Hardware ID is finally derived and sent to Microsoft during the activation process.

**How is the Installation ID validated?**

The Installation ID needs to be validated to confirm the authenticity of the installed copy of Windows. So, after the Installation ID is received by Microsoft, it is decoded back so as to obtain the actual product key and the hardware details of the computer involved in the activation process.

The Microsoft’s system will now look to see if this is the first time the product key is being used for the activation. This happens when the user is trying to activate his Windows for the first time after purchase. If so, the Installation ID is instantly validated and the corresponding Activation ID is issued which completes the activation process.

However, Microsoft system will now associate this product key with the hardware ID of the computer and stores this information on their servers. In simple words, during the first use of the product key, it is paired together with the Hardware ID and this information is stored up on the Microsoft servers.

**Some things WPA does not do**:

WPA does not send any personal information at all about you to Microsoft. There is still an option to register the product with Microsoft, but that is separate and entirely voluntary.
If you prefer to activate via phone, you are not required to give any personal information to Microsoft.
WPA does not provide a means for Microsoft to turn off your machine or damage your data/hardware. (Nor do they even have access to your data). This is a common myth that many people have about Microsoft products.
WPA is not a “lease” system requiring more payments after two years or any other period. You may use the product as licensed in perpetuity.

Additional reference notes taken from this [website](http://www.gohacking.com/how-windows-product-activation-works/)

Comment: This doesn't really answer the original question. The OP was asking about how the product key is validated during installation without an internet connection. The activation process happens separately and can fail even if the product key was accepted.

Answer (score 1):

It is simply an algorithm used by Microsoft to make sure that the key is a "valid" key, not a genuine non hacked/cracked/shared one.

The actual check to see if it is valid and activated happens later when you connect to the internet. If you have no internet, you will simply have an unactivated copy of Windows which will require internet access or a phone call within 30 days of installation.

Answer (score 0):

The key is checked by using a so called sum check. This is comparable with a bank account number. The sum of all individual numbers is divided by a number (usually 97, the highest prime number below 100). The remainder of the division are the last two numbers of the bank account number. The Windows key is checked in a similar way.

Comment: The information provided is not relevant to the question.

Comment: @suspectus How is my answer not relevant to the question? OP asked how a key is checked, I explained the method used. Just because I compared it with something else doesn't make it irrelevant, does it? Or am I missing something here?

Comment: The question is about how a windows key is verified *after* the correct key has been entered.

Comment: Yes, but a key can only be called correct after it has been verified. What would be the point of verifying a key that is already considered correct?

Comment: Apologies for any confusion. My distinction was between the syntax correctness and the key validity. Yes the key is correct syntactically (it's check sum value passes) and the service determining if the key is valid (the key has not already been registered say and is a valid Windows 8 key). The question is about how the key verification is made without an online check. If verification were just down to the check sum, anyone could copy the key and install windows on as many machines as they cared to.

Comment: Ok, now I get what you mean. You are absolutely right. :)