# How does Windows know whether to accept a COA key?

Tags: windows, windows-vista, license

I have an HP laptop with a Windows Vista Home Premium license. Apparently if I download a vista ISO and install it using this key, it would be accepted.

How does the setup know I'm using this key on the PC the sticker is on? Is it the Motherboard? What's stopping someone from installing the OS, removing the HDD and using it somewhere else after activating windows?

Comment: same applies to Vista: http://superuser.com/a/931101/174557

Comment: It does not know what pc the product key came from if the OS has Never been activated with that key, once activated the key is locked to that hardware configuration and cannot be activated on different hardware. (OEM product keys)

Comment: @magicandre1981 So replacing the hard drive would make the key unusable? According to that reply, the hard drive and VSN make the hardware ID, which would change if the drive was replaced. Right?